# Java: extracting a unique line of text with at least 10 Digits in a buffered reader

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract a unique line of text that has at least 10 digits, and a dash, letters, unique character etc using regular expressions and there after prints only the digits to the console.
I have the following to succeed but couldn't.

```
String texts =  "9 N l 00 I . \n ASSOCIATES TD '\nAB?! .1 A.\n 15 K V 2669-8 7030 ’ \n 5‘37?» 54 4’ 0630395026782582 § \n4654—8199-9146, < .*\nLE“; *1. 0501/2015 10:4 .1 AM g";

        BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(texts));
          List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
          for (String line = rdr.readLine(); line != null; line = rdr.readLine()) {
          System.out.println("The Buffered Reader lines are>>>>> "+lines.add(line));
          }
          for(String values : lines){

              String r="[^A-Za-z0-9]+"; 
             // String pp = "pmNo: 4:654—8199-9146, < .\\“ -";
              Matcher mm = Pattern.compile(r).matcher(values);
              System.out.println("2nd Special Found "+mm.find());
              boolean mb = mm.find();
              if(mb == true){
              System.out.println("The result>>>>> "+r); //I want to print 4654—8199-9146, < .*
                r = r.replaceAll("\\D+","");

                 System.out.println("The Buffered Reader lines are2>>>>> "+values); //I want to print 465481999146

            }



          }
          rdr.close();
```

Where am I not getting right?

Comment: A regex for a string containing at least 10 *consecutive* digits is `\\d{10,}`. For non-consecutive: `(?:\\D*\\d){10,}` (or `(?:[^\\d\n]\\d){10,}`). Note your `System.out.println("The result>>>>> "+r);` line will output `[^A-Za-z0-9]+`, not the found value. To output digits with hyphens, use `.replaceAll("[^0-9—–-]", "");` (add more exceptions to the negated character class if you need).

Comment: Can you add the expected output from the `texts` variable?